# React native keyboard blank space issue

Tags: react-native, expo, chat

Hello can you help me to solve following issue on my `ChatScreen`...

I am using `KeyboardAwareScrollView` and don't know how to handle automatically this blank space when user dismiss the keyboard.

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={[styles.content, center && styles.contentCenter]}
  scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  enableResetScrollToCoords={false}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  scrollIndicatorInsets={{ right: 1 }}
 >
  {children}
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
```

check these solutions [link] ([react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391717/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-not-working-properly))

Comment: Tnx from this link for me same solution (`react-native-keyboard-aware-view`) is wokring but I have another issue with that solution: `Unsupported layout animation createConfig property...`

Comment: check this out [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1135#issuecomment-98903335)

Comment: I have animation from vendor not my own.