# KeyboardAvoidingView is not working correctly when used inside a action sheet componet

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I have a form inside an **action sheet** and I'm trying to implement**KeyboardAvoidingView** to  not overwrite my **Input component** but nothing happens. I don't know exactly what's going on but when I use the [tag:behavior="position]" there is a difference but it deforms my component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfBXo.gif)

```
  return (
    <VStack mx={8}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS == "ios" ? 20 : 0}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <SafeAreaView>
            <Input
              placeholder="name"
              onChangeText={setName}
              value={name}
              w="full"
            />
            <Input
              placeholder="email"
              onChangeText={setEmail}
              value={email}
              w="full"
            />

            <VStack w="full">
              <SelectList
                placeholder={"Tipo Sanguíneo"}
                inputStyles={{
                  color: "#777272",
                  fontSize: 14,
                  padding: 0,
                }}
                setSelected={(val: string) => setSelected(val)}
                onSelect={() => console.log(selected)}
                data={roles.map((item) => item.name)}
                save="value"
                search={false}
                boxStyles={{
                  borderWidth: 0.5,
                  borderColor: "#80808060",
                  height: 43,
                  borderRadius: 3,
                }}
                dropdownStyles={{
                  bottom: 5,
                  borderWidth: 0.5,
                  borderColor: "#80808060",
                  borderRadius: 3,
                  paddingVertical: 0,
                  margin: 0,
                }}
                dropdownTextStyles={{
                  fontSize: 12,
                  padding: 0,
                }}
              />
            </VStack>

            <HStack my={5} space={3} alignSelf="center">
              <Button title="Cancelar" isOutline w="1/2" />
              <Button
                title="Adicionar"
                w="1/2"
                onPress={() =>
                  signUp({
                    name,
                    email,
                    roleId: selected,
                    bloodCenterId: authData?.bloodCenterId
                      ? authData?.bloodCenterId
                      : "",
                  }).then(childToParent(true))
                }
                textAlign="left"
                alignSelf="center"
              />
            </HStack>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </VStack>
  );
```

I tried to do it using flex and some styling but it deforms my entire container

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm library [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-view)

```
npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-view
```

and also you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391717/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view-not-working-properly)